# Value from one view's form to other view

Tags: django, return-value, redirect, django-views

Can I perform in django such operation, that in one view I assign a value of return from other view, that renders its own form template and basing on it returns value ? (So in other words if on this form rendered by the other function user clicks ok, I return true, and if user clicks cancel I return false) Sample code :

Main function:

```
def my_func(request):
    result = False
    result = redirect('some_url')

    if result:
        redirect somewhere
    else:
        redirect somewhere else
```

Child function called from parent with 'some_url' :

```
def some_url_func(request):
     if request.POST.get("action") == "ok":   
        return True
     elif if request.POST.get("action") == "cancel":
        return False
```

Form:

```
<form action="some_url_func" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" action="ok" value="Ok" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" action="cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

So basically is it possible to go through one view to some form and then return to this view ?

Comment: `my_func` makes no sense at all.  Anyway, your form's `action` should have the URL that refers to `some_url_func`.  What view renders the form is irrelevant.

Comment: So many things wrong with this. Your "child function" doesn't have any relation to the main function. It seems rather messy logic to have a function which can return either a boolean or an HttpResponse under different situations. Your form uses made up attributes on the input tags, and has an unnecessary enctype. On top of all of that, I can't even make sense on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: this is just the idea, so th'ts why It can make no sense. The idea behind this is as follows : "my_func shows a form. When the form is submitted it must open another form with two buttons : "Ok" and "Cancel". Depending on the choice my_func will performs some action. So how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above your first function makes no sense; but I think your main idea is that you can just call another function with your `request` and look at the returned value; but you shouldn't call it a view function if it doesn't return a `HttpResponse` object, it's just some sort of helper function. I think what you wanted to do is:

```
def my_func(request):
    result = some_url_func(request)
    if result:
        redirect somewhere
    else:
        redirect somewhere else
```

But maybe you should put your second function then in a module like `utils` since its more a helper function than a  view!